# DevTools and Webpack with local overrides

Tags: google-chrome, web, webpack, bundle, devtools

Using the Chromium browser (version 99.0.4844.0) I visit a website and open DevTools (F12), then I go to "Sources", "Overrides", paste a folder there.

Then I can make changes to files under "Sources" and "Page", which are also displayed after a page reload.

Under "Page" is the area "webpack://" (source mapped). The changes to the files there also appear in the "Changes" tab below, but they don't take effect.

How can I also make changes to the files in the "webpack://" area work?

With the latest Google Chrome version, "Save for overrides" does not work for webpack files under "Sources", "Page".